# Geometry of tangent space to Grassmannian

Tags: algebraic-geometry, tensor-products, projective-geometry, grassmannian

In considering what the dimension of a Grassmanian, $G(k,V)$, is, I came across an interesting property of the tangent space to a Grassmanian. Specifically, given $\mathbb{P}E \subset G(k,V)$, where $E$ is a vector space, we have that:

$$T_E \, G(k,V) \cong E^\ast \otimes V / E$$

Where: $T_E \, G(k,V)$ is the tangent space to the Grassmannian containing all derivatives of curves that start in $E$ and stay in the Grassmannian, $E^\ast$ is the dual space to $E$, and $V / E$ is the quotient space.

I don't know why this is true... It seems to me that if we consider a general curve in $G(k,V)$, it's given by $[c(t)] := [v_1(t) \wedge \cdots \wedge v_k(t)]$. Then, if $c(0) = v_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_k \in E$, where the $v_i$ are general (linearly independent) vectors in $E$, we can compute the tangent plane. Specifically:

$$c^\prime (0) = V \wedge v_2 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_k + \cdots + v_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_{k-1} \wedge V \in T_E \, G(k,V)$$

Where, above, the sum is not direct, and the expression gives a general vector in the tangent plane. Then, how can we construct an isomorphism to $E^\ast \otimes V /E$?

Comment: $\Bbb PE\subset G(k,V)$ seems like a weird way to say $E\in G(k,V)$. Also, quotient space is $V/E$, set-theoretic complement is $V\setminus E$.

Comment: @arctictern, $E$ is a vector space, not a point in the Grassmannian. Thanks for the note about the quotient notation.

Comment: Intuitive reason : if $E \in G(k,V)$ then a tangent vector at $E$ is exactly a little linear deformation of $E$ given by $e_i \mapsto e_i + v_i$, i.e a map $\psi \in Hom(E,V)$. But of course, if $v_i \in E$ the deformation is trivial, it follows that the "real" tangent vector space are $Hom(E,V/E) \cong E^* \otimes V/E$.

Comment: How does $T_E G(k,V)$ make sense unless $E\in G(k,V)$? Also, how does $\Bbb PE\subset G(k,V)$ make sense if $\Bbb PE$ contains $1$-dimensional subspaces and $G(k,V)$ contains $k$-dimensional subspaces of $V$?